# Are unsigned integer types always of different sizes?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Is it possible (conforming to the C spec) to have 2 unsigned integer types of different *ranges* yet of the same *size* (due to padding)?

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Size:%zu  Max:%llu\n", 
      sizeof(unsigned_32_t), (unsigned long long) ((unsigned_32_t) -1));
  // Size:4 Max:4294967295

  printf("Size:%zu  Max:%llu\n", 
      sizeof(unsigned_24_t), (unsigned long long) ((unsigned_24_t) -1));
  // Size:4 Max:16777215

  return 0;
```

Not using *Exact-width integer types*, which cannot have padding.

Certainly this is not common - just wondering what the spec allows.

Comment: Somehow the title doesn't completely match the question.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh _Exact-width integer types_ such as `uint24_t` and `uint32_t` have different ranges but are specified to not have padding - they must be of different sizes.  So _exact-width integer types_ are not proof other unsigned types must have different sizes.

Comment: @juanchopanza  Agree the connection is weak - do you have a suggestion - edit title at your pleasure.

Comment: The more interesting question is how would you tell the compiler you have a new type that's half-way between an `unsigned short` and `unsigned`? All the other `uintN_t` types are defined in terms of other primary types (e.g. `unsigned short int`, `unsigned int`, ...)

Comment: @David C. Rankin "All the other `uintN_t` types are defined in terms of other primary types" is not specified by C.  I've worked with an embedded platform that have `uint24_t` and `uint48_t` and these types are not `unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned, unsigned long, unsigned long long` which are 8,16,16,32,64 bits.  Such types like `uint24_t` can exist without matching some other type.  Also exact width types like `uint32_t` are not even required to exist.

Comment: That explains it! (must think out of the x86 box more often..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes, this is absolutely possible.

For the specific case of the `uintN_t` types defined in `<stdint.h>`, as you noted (C11 §7.20.1.1):

> The typedef name uintN_t designates an unsigned integer type with width N
>   and no padding bits. Thus, uint24_t denotes such an unsigned integer
>   type with a width of exactly 24 bits.

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely plausible that a system with a 36-bit memory bus and nine-bit `char` might, as a compatibility aid, include 8-bit, 16-bit, and 32-bit unsigned types(*) which wrap mod 256, 65536, and 4294967296, respectively.  Such types would use the same amount of storage as 9, 18, and 36-bit types, and would be stored essentially the same way, except that operations would mask off the upper bits.  Given a 16-bit unsigned variable `u`, a compiler could either implement `u++` to be equivalent to `u=(u+1) & 65535;` and implement `u>23` as an 18-bit compare, or could implement `u++` as an 18-bit increment and implement `u>23` as `(u & 65535)>23`.

(*) The Standard dictates that if `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, and `uint32_t` are all defined, they must be stored using 8, 16, or 32 bits *and no padding bits*, so if a standards-compliant compiler for a 36-bit machine defines such power-of-two sized types, it must use other names; unfortunately, the Standard provides standard name for types which behave properly numerically but do not satisfy the expected storage layout.

Comment: Did you mean "the Standard provides *no* standard name"? BTW, there are also `uint_leastN_t` and `uint_fastN_t`. I suspect the standard doesn't provide a name for, e.g., a type with that behaves like `uintN_t` but may have one or more padding bits because the need for such a type is rare. Cluttering `<stdint.h>` with an even larger variety of type names would not necessarily be a good thing (though arguably the requirements for `intN_t` are stricter than they need to be).

Comment: @KeithThompson: A type like `uint_least16_t` is not guaranteed to wrap mod 65536 (and is in fact unlikely to do so).  As for type-name clutter, I think having a syntax to specify things parametrically would be better than having a huge number of identifiers, since while the number of parameters I would like to see isn't all that large, the total number of types one could construct from them would be, and since defining interactions between types parametrically would allow much cleaner rules than trying to define interactions between every possible combination of separately-named types.

Comment: Actually `uint_least16_t` is very likely to wrap mod 65536; it will do so in any implementation that can support `uint16_t`. But you're right, it's not guaranteed. A parameterized integer type declaration syntax would be nice to have, but fitting it into the existing language could be difficult, and I don't expect to see it happen. The `[u]intN_t` types are adequate for systems that have 8-, 16-, 32-, and 64-bit integers and that use 2's-complement -- and these days that's the vast majority of modern systems.

Comment: Someone could devise a parameterized integer type definition syntax and write a translator from that syntax to standard C, given information about the target C implementation. It would be an interesting project, it might be useful, and if successful it could encourage standardization in future C standard. On the other hand, the fact that I've never heard of such a project likely indicates a lack of demand for it.

Comment: @KeithThompson: A suitably-designed parameterized type system could enable many relatively-straightforward and non-surprising optimizations which would not be legal under today's type system. For example, if a loop uses an index of type `int32_t`, a compiler would be entitled to assume it can't wrap if `int` is 32 bits, but *not if `int` is 64 bits*.  If a structure containing a 16-bit integer is loaded into a local variable and modified heavily while there, but never has its address taken, it may be useful for the compiler to regard its members as separate variables in separate registers...

Comment: ...with the 16-bit `integer` being promoted to 32 or 64 bits (so `foo.x=32767; foo.x++;` would be allowed to make `foo.x` hold 32768 rather than having defined behavior dictated that it must hold -32768) but there's no means by which a programmer can authorize such an optimization.  I would posit that the value of optimizations that would be straightforwardly enabled by type system improvements would far outweigh the total value of all possible optimizations that would be enabled through eliminating all forms of UB that code doesn't rely upon.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Further, more generally, I would think it feasible, and a worthwhile goal, to add a means by which the vast majority of existing straightforwardly-written code for most platforms could be adapted to have a *single defined meaning* on every platform capable of compiling it, merely by adding and changing some declarations and standardized compiler directives.  C has historically been a systems-programming language.  Present trends are making it unsuitable for that purpose by taking forms of Undefined Behavior which historically meant "do whatever the hardware does"...

Comment: ...[which is of course often necessary in systems programming] and replacing them with "assume no chain of events that would make them happen can occur". It's funny that people arguing for such treatment suggest I should use assembly language, when *the whole reason C was invented* was to minimize the need for assembly language in systems programming.  Giving programmers fine control when they need it, but allowing them to give the compiler freedom when they don't, would improve the usefulness of the language for both systems and application programming.

Comment: You might consider collecting your thoughts into a blog post or something similar rather than scattering them across comments here.